# Evaluating the limit : $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+k}}$

Tags: summation, riemann-sum

This kind of question always baffles me. It looks like the answer is 0 but it isn't.

Can anyone tell me what does go on? And how do you evaluate this limit?
$$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+k}}$$

Comment: Hint: pull out a(nother) factor of $1/\sqrt{n}$ from the terms in the sum and see if you can recognize a Riemann sum in the result.

Comment: The sum is equal to 
$$\frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+ \frac kn}} \to \int_0^1 (1+t)^{-\frac12} dt = 2(\sqrt{2} -1).$$

Comment: @nguyen0610 How do you transform the sum into an integral?

Comment: Also, note that the sum is bounded from below by $\sum_{k=1}^n1/\sqrt{n+n}$ $=(1/\sqrt{2})\sum_{k=1}^n1/\sqrt{n}$ $=(1/\sqrt{2})(n\times 1/\sqrt{n})$ $=\sqrt{n}/\sqrt{2}$, so your limit certainly can't be zero.

Comment: @user599663: this is tagged [tag:riemann-sum].

Comment: Please give more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960). Providing context not only assures that this is not simply copied from a homework assignment, but also allows answers to be better directed at where the problem lies and to be within the proper scope. Please [avoid "I have no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/27933). Defining keywords and trying a simpler, similar problem often helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With or without taking a limit, there is a standard comparison between sum and integral of the same thing. Given real function $f(x)$ with
$$  f > 0 \; , \; \; f' < 0  $$
and integers $a < b,$ 
$$  \int_a^{b+1} \; f(x) dx  < \sum_{j=a}^b f(j) < \int_{a-1}^{b} \; f(x) dx$$

For you,
$$ \int_{1}^{n+1} \; \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+n}} \; dx < \sum_{k=1}^n  \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+n}} <   \int_{0}^{n} \; \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+n}} \; dx$$

[image]

AFTERTHOUGHT: if you have a different problem with $f' >0$ both inequalities reverse, see [Did I misuse the inductive hypothesis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2904471/did-i-misuse-the-inductive-hypothesis/2904482#2904482)

Comment: (+1) nice pictures :)

Answer (score 1):

Given

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+k}} = \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n} \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+k}}=\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n} \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+\dfrac{k}{n}}}$

> $\because \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n} \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\dfrac{k}{n}\right) = \displaystyle \int_0^1 f(x) \mathrm dx$

$\implies \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+k}} = \displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}} \mathrm dx  = \displaystyle {\left. 2\sqrt{1+x}\right|_0^1}= 2\sqrt{1+1}-2\sqrt{1+0}= 2\sqrt2-2 $

$\boxed{\therefore\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+k}}= \displaystyle{2\sqrt2-2}}$